# Grouping dataset by tags

Tags: dataset, associations

Here is a slight modificaiton of Mathematica's example dataset from the documentation:

```
ds = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "team" -> {"John"}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "team" -> {"Mary", "Alice"}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "team" -> {"Alice"}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "team" -> {"Lucas", "Charlie"}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "team" -> {"Charlie", "Bobby", "Ana"}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "team" -> {}|>}]
```

Grouping by columns "a" or "b" is easy. But how could I group by column "team" (taking into account, of course, the different entries)?

I think of this as e.g. a dataset containing active projects within a company, and "team" is the list of people involved. What I want to do then is to group the projects by the people involved.

The way I found to do this is as

```
staff = {"John","Mary", "Alice","Lucas", "Charlie", "Bobby", "Ana"};

Dataset[Association[Table[person -> ds[Select[MemberQ[#team, person] &]], {person, 
staff}]]]
```

But it doesn't look great. And I am not convinced this is the proper way of handling this type of query. This seems like a standard problem and there should be a proper way of dealing with it. But I can't seem to find out.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
ds[Query@GroupBy[First -> Last], Splice@Thread[#team -> #] &]
```

[image: dataset screeenshot]

Unlike the expression given in the question, this does not produce nested datasets.  But if nested datasets are desired, then:

```
ds[Query[GroupBy[First->Last], Dataset], Splice@Thread[#team -> #] &]
```

[image: nested datasets]

Comment: Awesome. This works perfectly. Thank you!